# Rules content unpublish in 30 days

Tags: rules

I've followed this thread https://groups.drupal.org/node/240678#comment-782543, but that's based on a date field and it has a different scenario.

My idea is: When a new content is created, after 30 days will be automatically unpublished.

How can I achieve this without using additional date fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use [Auto Expire](https://drupal.org/project/auto_expire) module, Using this module you can set the node to unpublish after 30 days.

[image]

For your case set zero in purge field, otherwise it will automatically delete from database.

> This module allows site administrators to set expiration times for
>   content types.
>
> End users creating content that has auto expiry set cannot control the
>   expiry time. They could be allowed to renew the content for one or
>   more cycles.